Gradient Descent Logistic Regression and Covariate Scaling
I'm trying to understand logistic regression and gradient descent. How hard can it be, right? Well, I used the example from this website
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
logistic = glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + factor(rank), data = mydata, family="binomial")
betahat = logistic$coefficients

Okay, so that's what the gradient descent should converge to. I brought the data into a classic format and implemented the gradient of the logit regression (or did I?)
# data in classic format
X = cbind(1, mydata$gre, mydata$gpa, mydata$rank==2, mydata$rank==3, mydata$rank==4)
y = mydata$admit

# logit gradient
logistic_cost_gradient <- function(X, y, b){
  yhat  = 1/(1+exp(-X %*% b))
  grad  = as.vector(crossprod(X, (y-yhat)))/nrow(X)
  return(grad)
}

# sanity check: gradient at optimum close to zero
logistic_cost_gradient(X,y,betahat)
# sanity check passed 

So let's try some gradient descent:
b = rep(0,ncol(X)) # starting value

epoch = 1          # gradient descent steps

while(epoch<1000){
  grad = logistic_cost_gradient(X,y,b)
  b = b - grad/epoch # decreasing step size
  epoch = epoch + 1
  #print(b)
}

I know, it's a crude stopping criterion, but it doesn't seem to matter. The resulting values are garbage. What is going wrong?
My only guess is that it has to do with the scale of the second column of X, it's much larger than all the others. I would expect that if I divide a column by 100, the coefficient for that column would have to be multiplied with 100. This seems to be true:
mydata$gre = mydata$gre/100 
logistic_rescale = glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + factor(rank), data = mydata, family="binomial")
betahat_rescale = logistic_rescale$coefficients


Perhaps the gradient descent has issues with the scale of X? No matter what scaling of X I tried, I kept getting garbage results from gradient descent. Any hints? I'm loosing my head over this.
Edit: I also checked whether there is a sign mistake in the gradient. Even when I change the sign of the gradient, I get garbage values.
This is also not due to the data being undercomplex, as here, the fitted values for the probabilities are between 6% and 75%.

It may be an issue with the step size. I thought that the decreasing step size works with concave objectives, but it seems to work with the Hessian.
